# Recommended layout for testing integration of pallets

Tags: frame, testing, mock, loose-coupling

I've been working on a pallet in isolation for a few months. I did testing by mocking a runtime and mocking the related pallets that are expected by it. Basically, so far I have created fake pallets in a `mock` directory and used those in place of the ones that my pallet expects to be loosely coupled with. Here's my directory structure (roughly)

```
frame/my-pallet/
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── benchmarking.rs
    ├── lib.rs
    ├── mock
    │   ├── accounts.rs
    │   ├── assets.rs
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   ├── pallet1.rs
    │   ├── pallet2.rs
    │   └── runtime.rs
    ├── tests
    │   ├── mod.rs
    │   ├── extrinsic1.rs
    │   ├── extrinsic2.rs
    │   └── extrinsic3.rs
    ├── helpers.rs
    └── weights.rs
```

I now wanna do tests with a real implementation of `pallet1`, but I wanna keep the test cases with the mocked version. Is there a 'canonical' way of doing that? I'm considering just adding a `integrations` subdirectory under `src` and having new `mock.rs` and `tests.rs` files there.

Comment: Have you considered [Zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet)?

Comment: Not yet, does that facilitate automated tests of scenarios where two or more pallets are involved?

Answer (score 1):

Any pallet is just a Rust crate. Adding the "real" `pallet1` as a dependency to `Cargo.toml` will make it available to be imported anywhere in your project.

Comment: Yes, but I guess what I'm asking is how to have multiple mocked runtimes in my test directory, so that I can have tests with mocked dependencies (which have some auxiliary calls not present in real pallets) and tests with 'real' dependencies